# android spacing between touchable UI components clarification

Tags: android

[According to the official Android Design Documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html),  touchable UI components should be at least 48 dp high and at least 48 dp wide,

`On average, 48dp translate to a physical size of about 9mm (with some variability). This is comfortably in the range of recommended target sizes (7-10 mm) for touchscreen objects and users will be able to reliably and accurately target them with their fingers..`

[image: Android metrics and design]

While the image here shows that the items are contained to a 48dp row, the actual bounds of the UI components fall less than that (, with the pencil icon maxing out 32 dp and the button maxing out 40 dp (vertically).  Does this image indicate differently than how I have interpreted the information?

To add to this, the design documents indicate that touchable UI components should be spaced 8dp from eachother.  However, items in the action bar do not have 8 db of spacing between the touchable region between them.  Below are screenshots of action bar items in the official Gmail app.

[image: Gmail action bar shot 1]

[image: Gmail action bar shot 2]

In fact I can't think of any google app that actually has 8dp of just space between UI components.  Am I misinterpreting these guidelines?  Should there be no margin space between items but just padding space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google can spit on own standards when they want.
See also my question here: [Is navigation in iosched 13 application correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941913/is-navigation-in-iosched-13-application-correct)